# scp open source implementation for linux

Tags: linux, open-source, embedded, scp

I have an embedded box which is using linux. But it does not have an scp server running in it. Can anyone recommend some open source implementation(command line) so that i can cross compile and use the binary.

Comment: you need ssh. scp is an utility which runs on ssh

Comment: is there any implementation for that?

Answer (score 2):

You need to cross compile OpenSSH for your embedded device,Follow below steps

Download OpenSSH from http://ftp.openbsd.org/pub/OpenBSD/OpenSSH/portable/openssh-6.6p1.tar.gz
extract it and cross-compile it using toolchain

```
./configure --host="board architecture"

make
```

Copy sshd from compiled source and download it in your embedded device and run it

/path/sshd

Try to connect with your embedded device using scp